SQL Query Sum Group by
I have a table similar to structure below
table 
ID EmployeeID factor
1.  100       A
2.  100       B
2.  100       C


my requirement is for a given EmployeeID I need to replace the factor with numerical values and sum the factor where A = 1 , B=2 and C=3
using a select query I was able to replace the values and see the table
select employeeid,
       case factor
        WHEN 'F' THEN 4
        WHEN 'EC' THEN 2
        WHEN 'E' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END as factor
        From employee
        where employee_id = 100

but when I try to use sum and group by on this getting query syntax error
select employeeid,count(*) as count
       sum(case factor
        WHEN 'F' THEN 4
        WHEN 'EC' THEN 2
        WHEN 'E' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END as factor) as factor
        From employee
        where employee_id = 100
        group by employeeid,count



You can’t have “count” in your GROUP BY

You don't put as factor inside the sum() argument.

If you're only selecting one employee ID, there's no need for GROUP BY.

You're using both employeeid and employee_id. One of them is probably wrong.

It's unclear what you want to do. Please read How To Make A Good Example and improve your question. It should include both sample input data and the expected result.

Use GROUP BY and HAVING to fetch data for particular employee after grouping data with that key.
Also correct the SUM(CASE...END) statement
So, SQL query should be:
select employeeid,
    count(*) as count, 
    sum(
      CASE (factor)
        WHEN 'F' THEN 4
        WHEN 'EC' THEN 2
        WHEN 'E' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
   ) as factor
From employee
group by employeeid
having employeeid = 100

Sample Query: db<>fiddle

No need for a HAVING clause, their purpose is to check aggregated conditions. The condition employeeid = 100 can just be checked in a standard WHERE clause. Overall, I'm not sure if the logic in your answer is what OP want to do, they should improve their question.

In this question add condition where groupid=100, that means actuall db table have multiple groupid. That's why I added, if not then not required having...

I don't understand what you try to say, anyway, here you see a simple WHERE clause is enough: https://dbfiddle.uk/z0PQ1jOI You only need HAVING for aggregations.

@JonasMetzler I checked your query, truthly saying I didn't use any SQL query your way (where & next group by), if I used everywhere group by & having. But it's working, It's great learning for me... Thank you ...

Create table Emp (ID int, EmployeeID int, factor nvarchar(2))

insert into emp(ID,EmployeeID,factor)
VALUES
(1,  100,       'A'),
(2,  100 ,      'B'),
(2,  100  ,     'C')
with CTE
AS
(
    select ID,
    EmployeeID,factor,
    case factor
        WHEN 'A' THEN 1
        WHEN 'B' THEN 2
        WHEN 'C' THEN 3
        ELSE 0
        END as factor2
    
    from emp
    where EmployeeID=100
)
select EmployeeID,factor,Sum(factor2) over(partition by EmployeeID) SumOfFactore
from CTE

